# Exception that gets caught for some reason bubbles up to another catch block

Tags: .net

We have an unusual case, a try-catch block inside another try-catch block. Both catch clauses catch Exception type of exceptions. Error that occurs in the most inner try-catch block, gets caught byt the first catch that is empty and instead of moving to the next line, it gets caught another time by the other catch. This is something I have never seen before. One of our colleagues claims that this is some setting but he does not remember what kind of setting. Do you know why is this happening and how to "turn it off"?
Please find the code below:

```
    try {
        //some code                                
        try
        {
               //code that throws exception                           

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
         //some other code, never reached

        }  
   catch (Exception ex)  
   {
           Logger.Write(ex.ToString());
           return null;  
   }
```

Comment: Show some real code.

Comment: What's the "handling" part of the first catch block? Does it involve rethrowing the exceptoin?

Comment: There is definitely an exception thrown within the first (i.e. _inner_) `catch` block. Can you provide more relevant code?

Comment: I have never seen this behaviour.

Comment: If the "handling" code throws an exception, it will "bubble" up to the next catch block.

Comment: What is the type of your exception? There are some exceptions like `ThreadAbortedException` which you can catch, but it will be rethrown by the run time.

Comment: sorry for that - first catch block does not do ANYTHING. no retrowing can be involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that could be causing this is that your first catch block is also throwing an exception. This would cause the second one to be triggered.

Your colleague may be referring to the exception catching functionality of Visual Studio which allows you to break on any exceptions including ones that have already been handled. You can find this by pressing CTRL + ALT + e, or in the menus it's listed under Debug --> Extensions...

If neither of those are the case then we'll need more code

Comment: first catch block is completely empty. sorry for the misunderstanding - i've corrected the post

Comment: The "Debug -> Extensions" settings seem like the most likely culprit.

Comment: Debug -> Exceptions? And what there?

Comment: "Thrown" wants to be unticked, and "user un-handled" wants to be ticked

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the //handling to do nothing and see if it's still occur if so the //handling section is either causing an exception or throw the exception

Answer (score 0):

I have two followups:

1. Does this happen only on your vs or on others as well ?

   - if this happens only on yours - it probably is Ctrl+Alt+E, setting up the debugging and breaks
2. Are you running an exception block ? maybe your exception handling block is malconfigured ?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a finally block instead of writing your "other code" after the try-catch block

Comment: this does not explain the behaviour in any way and I try to understand why this is happenning